# How to do a git clone from an azure repo through docker?

Tags: git, azure, docker, automation, azure-repos

I'm currently trying to find the best way to do a git clone from a private azure repo through a docker file. I'm able to do it with Github, but I don't know how to do it from Azure Pipelines.

The github example is by doing this:

```
FROM node as builder

COPY github_key .
RUN eval $(ssh-agent) && \
    ssh-add github_key && \
    ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts && \
    git clone git@github.com:phillies/vue_example.git /opt/vue_example
WORKDIR /opt/vue_example
RUN npm install && npm run build


FROM nginx

COPY --from=builder /opt/vue_example/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Does anyone knows how to do it through azure repos?

Comment: My general experience has been that it's easier and more flexible to run `git clone` outside of Docker; maybe even check the Dockerfile and similar artifacts into the repository.  In the setup you show it's very easy to accidentally leak an ssh private key, and you can't build an image from a non-master branch or from uncommitted code.

Comment: Yeah, this is just for testing because what I can do is to create a container registry that will be holding the repo. In that case, I can use the repo or any file that I need..

Comment: Have you tried just repeating this, but with your azure pipelines repo URL and private key? What problem do you encounter when you attempt that?